# int changing values in nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to create a Lottery game where this method prints the name of the player the number of int in common with the Lottery array and somme is the amount of money they won.
When I run the program to check who won the g value only increase by one with the player number. For example, if I create 2 players and in the first one I type all the right numbers and the 2nd all wrong ones, I'll get that for player1 I only have 1 correct answer and for number2 2 correct answers.

```
public void checkWinner() {

    double somme;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                if (Joueur[i].getArray()[j] == gridLoto()[k]) {
                    g++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (g == 1) {
            somme = (double)mise / 32;
        System.out.println("Bravo " + Joueur[i].getNom() + ", vous avez " + g
                    + " nombre en commun avec la grille du loto et vous avez donc remporté " + somme + " €");
        }
        . 
        .//else if with g=2 to 4 here
        .
        else if (g == 5) {
            somme = (double)mise / 2;
        System.out.println("Bravo " + Joueur[i].getNom() + ", vous avez " + g
                    + " nombre en commun avec la grille du loto et vous avez donc remporté " + somme + " €");
        }
}
```

Comment: Where (which line) `g` is initialized? Should not it be reset for each new `i`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is with the way the variable `g` is declared. I believe it should be declared as 0 at the start of the first loop.

There are also other improvements that could be made. You don't need 5 separete if statements for checking how many correct numbers were selected. You could do it in one line:
`System.out.println("Bravo " + Joueur[i].getNom() + ", vous avez " + g + " nombre en commun avec la grille du loto et vous avez donc remporté " + CalculateSomme(g) + " €");` , where
`double CalculateSomme (int g)` would hold the logic for calculating the sum.

Another major improvement you could do is to store the arrays of correct numbers and guesses as Sets and then use the `retainAll` method of Set class.